# How to re-index all content of a certain type?

Tags: plone

I would like to re-index all content of a particular type, just once.

Should I make a python script in the zmi?

This is what I have so far

```
from zope.component.hooks import getSite

site = getSite()
items = site.contentItems()
items.reindexObject()
```

I am not sure how to specify the type... or if I am on the right track. Are there any examples of doing this kind of operation that I can dissect?

Comment: Generally on http://docs.plone.org you can find nearly everything, and specially for simple things like that.

Comment: Question: generally an object is already reindexed when modified, wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: The docs don't really make anything seem simple... until you see the API section!
I changed the way it indexes, and it is dependent on child items now, so I need to re-index the exsisting parents without clearing the children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would actually to use the catalog for that:

```
import plone.api

catalog = plone.api.portal.get_tool(name='portal_catalog')
for brain in catalog(portal_type='My portal type'):
    obj = brain.getObject()
    obj.reindexObject()
```

That would do it.

Notice that I used only plone.api calls, so your code would be future proof.

Comment: Dies this set the modification date to the actual date?

Comment: No, you're only reindexing the object, not modifying it.

Comment: You can also specify which indexes you want to reindex to speed up the process; for instance, obj.reindexObject(idxs=['Title']) or obj.reindexObject(idxs=['modified'])

Comment: I tested this solution (because it seems a lot cooler than what I commonly do) but is not working:

>>> catalog(portal_type='Document')[0].reindexObject()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: reindexObject() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: This is what inspector says about method signature:

    >>> import inspect
    >>> print(inspect.getargspec(catalog(portal_type='Document')[0].reindexObject))
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'object', 'idxs', 'update_metadata', 'uid'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=([], 1, None))

Comment: @gforcada: looks like you are calling reindexObject on a catalog brain. You should get the object instead: brain.getObject().reindexObject()

Comment: thanks for noticing it, I already fixed it, I was missing the ``getObject()``

Comment: So I remove my upvote to that aswer: this is not always a good solution cebause calling reindexObject on the object will also update the modification date and calling reindexObject(idxs=[...] will not update modification date but also not update metadata.

Comment: @keul the question was about "reindexing content" and that's what my answer is about, if you have a different use case, that's fine, but that doesn't mean I don't answer the user question...

Comment: @gforcada absolutely, and you answer *is* a right one! I just added a usecase because in my experience the reindexObject side effect is not always something that user expects (I mean: reindexing 1000 Page and seeing modification date updated)

Comment: I get an 'insufficient privileges' message when trying to visit the path of this script, or when clicking on the test tab (as admin). Is there another way I should be executing it?

Answer (score 3):

A solution we use:

```
import plone.api

catalog = plone.api.portal.get_tool(name='portal_catalog')
for brain in catalog(portal_type='My portal type'):
    obj = brain.getObject()
    catalog.catalog_object(obj)
```

Using `catalog_object` method from ZCatalog is the same API used by the ZMI "Update" feature:

[image: ZMI Catalog update]

Pros: modification date is not updated, you are simply reindexing the catalog data
Cons: you can't use this API from restricted Python (while you can call `obj.reindexObject`)

If you don't have problem about modification date changes, the gforcata answer is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This script gives me a permissions error too.